# Telerik RadCartesianChart - Lines rendered outside the chart

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, telerik

We are trying to plot a simple graph with a Y axis from 0 to 5. The data may sometimes be outside the range. The lines are rendered even if they are outside of the specified minimum and maximum.

Here is an example of what it looks like with this data :

```
Data = new double[6] { -5, 0.5, 5, 0.5, 2, 1 };
```

[Outside points test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jcI9.png)

Here is the code :

```
        <telerikChart:RadCartesianChart Height="300" Margin="0,16,0,0">
          <telerikChart:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
            <telerikChart:CategoricalAxis ShowLabels="False"/>
          </telerikChart:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
          <telerikChart:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
            <telerikChart:LinearAxis />
          </telerikChart:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
          <telerikChart:LineSeries x:Name="Chart" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Data, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </telerikChart:RadCartesianChart>
```

Comment: Could you tell us what is the data that you bind to? I test the code that has no issue.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I updated the post with a simple test and a picture of it.

Comment: I use your code that there is no issue.Could you tell us more detail about your OS version of your Windows and your VS SDK?

Comment: Visual studio 2015 targeting windows 10 anniversary. OS version : 15063.502

Comment: Should my chart be in a particular container ?

Comment: Please try to set the RadCartesianChart in a blank page, is there any issue?